# Use custom middleware for async actions - when dipactching thunk action

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

i dont know why this one is causing me problems. i have dispatched a lot of thunks and this was suppose to be a simple one.

this is my store:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './reducers';
import logger from 'redux-logger';
import CircularJSON from 'circular-json';

let store;

const persistedState = localStorage.getItem('storeState') ?
                      JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('storeState')):
                      {}

store = 
createStore(rootReducer,persistedState,applyMiddleware(thunk,logger));
```

this is the action creator:

```
export async function fetchSrcContorlTrendChartData(){ 
 return async (dispatch)=>{
   let data = await getChartsData();
   dispatch({type:C.FETCH_SRC_CONTROL_TREND_CHART_DATA,payload:data})
  }
}//fetchS
```

this is the grtChartsData function :

```
export function getChartsData(){
  return {
    "labels": 
  ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'],
  "gitActiveReposByMonth":[1,4,6,7,7,7,9,10,24,56,45,23],
  "TFVCActiveReposByMonth":[23,18,15,15,15,6,17,12,23,12,8,3],
  }; 
 }//getChartsData
```

any help will be great thnks

Answer (score 0):

I read you code but I couldn't figure out what problem exactly are you facing or how is the code you've shown is related to a custom middleware ?

The only problem I see is that you are calling a non-async function "getChartsData()" with await, and you don't need to

You could change it to

```
export function fetchSrcContorlTrendChartData() {
    return (dispatch)=>{
        let data = getChartsData();
        dispatch({type:C.FETCH_SRC_CONTROL_TREND_CHART_DATA,
           payload:data
        })
    }
}//fetchS
```

but even better you actually don't need a thunk at all

```
export function fetchSrcContorlTrendChartData() {
    return {
        type: C.FETCH_SRC_CONTROL_TREND_CHART_DATA,
        payload: getChartsData();
    }
}
```